# How to implement horizontal circular scroll wheel in android?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, android-wheel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make android-wheel horizontal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638927/how-to-make-android-wheel-horizontal)

I want to make horizontal circular scrolling wheel like this. Please suggest me how can I achieve it.

[image]

Comment: Show us your homework.

Comment: @Androiduser Can I get some sample code for this?

Comment: @Androiduser while using this it shows The type Gallery is deprecated any alternative